# Transformation of Two gammas

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

> A is distribution $\Gamma(k,1)$ and B is a distribution $\Gamma(a,c)$. Find the distribution of $X = A/B.$

I'm not sure how to start as I tried the cdf method and I could not get the answer.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ have to be independent to get an answer. In a special case under independence, the ratio has a [beta distribution of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution) which is easy to derive using a change of variables.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/207595/119261